# Dynamic column name or alias in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I am having trouble getting a subquery to work as a dynamic column alias. Basically I'm looking for something close to this:

```sql
select state1 as (select state1name from statelabels) from statetracker
```

The subquery only returns a single record but it still isn't working. How can pull this off? I found a close but no cookie example that required case but it wasn't a perfect fit.

Comment: Is there only the 1 field in the query?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a query as an alias. This is not supported.